# As a mastermind, can I dominate multiple enemies at once?

Tags: payday-2

As as mastermind, you can intimidate enemies.

> **DOMINATOR**
>
> BASIC: You can now intimidate non-special enemies. Less well trained enemies
>   are easier to intimidate.
>
> ACE: The power and range of your intimidation is increased.

In [this video (bank heist 100% stealth)](http://youtu.be/lwg7qC0aCH4), a player seems able to intimidate as many guards as he wants, the key point being to start yelling when the red excalamation point appears.  But it's not possible to *chain* intimidations this way anymore (I tried it myself), as it's stated in one of the video's comments:

[image: "This was before they nerfed the ability to 1 guy ever couple of minutes or so I'm afraid."]

So it is possible to intimidate another enemy after a certain time ?  How long ?

Comment: I would assume the cooldown is as long as the pager's after the 2nd answer

Comment: ... there's a cooldown after the pager's second answer ? xD

Comment: Not sure, never managed to wait long enough. The 3rd time you answer a pager, it always seems to fail, unless you have Smooth Talker from Mastermind. They might be related.

Comment: @ColeBusbyakacheat117cole108 these are completely different abilities.

Comment: @kotekzot you're right my apologies

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I dominate my enemies?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/130744/how-can-i-dominate-my-enemies)

Comment: Maybe they're aiming at them first. Or not specifically. You can do 4 on consoles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rules for this were changed 5th of March 2014 (emphasis mine):

> **Every player with the Dominator skill can now dominate one guard each at the same time.** But apparently the old pager operators got fired, and more experienced operators are taking over. So clear your throats, and get ready to answer the pager as soon as you dominate a guard.

So one dominated guard or police officer per player with dominator. That means **no, you cannot dominate multiple guards at once**. You will need a friend to help.

*Before this change* the rule (which console and unpatched versions might still follow) was one dominated guard or police at a time. Want another one? Kill the existing one.

Answer (score 3):

The video you were watching was in the beta of payday2 there you could dominate multiple guards without a problem. But they nerfed the perk, which now only allows 1 guard to be dominated, after 1 guard you will not be able to dominate another unless you kill the dominated guard.

Comment: I would dispute this answer. Yesterday, I ran a complete stealth run of Framing Frame that was based entirely off of one person chain-dominating guards. The first and last day, there were over four guards that ended up cuffing themselves, with no killing involved. There was a bit of a delay between each one, but I do not believe that there is a limit on how many enemies may be dominated. It is possible that this is being confused with the Joker perk, which allows a hostile NPC to be turned ally.

Comment: @Confuzzledmaniac Yeah indeed one after the other, he dominated the first then either cuffed or killed the guard then the next. I am saying that there may only be one guard dominated at a time by one person.

Comment: Getting a guard to cuff himself is an almost instantaneous action, so unless you are trying to dominate a group of guards at the same time (which doesn't seem like it should work anyways), it matters not.

Comment: @Confuzzledmaniac But he ziptied them afterwards, else it is impossible or buggy. Because cuffing themselves counts towards your one.

Comment: That doesn't make sense at all, if you have them cuff themselves you're effectively taking them out of the game unless you kill them afterwards. To my knowledge, it isn't even possible to ziptie an enemy that has already cuffed themself.

Comment: @Confuzzledmaniac Hmm, i remember being able to tie them before they cuff themselves. http://steamcommunity.com/app/218620/discussions/0/864976115527315862/?l=english , http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/682607-payday-2/66994557 , http://steamcommunity.com/app/218620/discussions/0/864976115782785810/ all speak over 1 dominate target.

Comment: The PC version and the Xbox version are not on the same patch release, apparently. Xbox version is unpatched, and you're correct, the Dominator skill is supposed to work as you said. It appears for the time being, the two are out of sync and that's why there is the discrepancy.

Comment: @Confuzzledmaniac Ah, I did not know that, thank you.

Comment: On consoles 4 gaurds can be dominated by the player with the skill(no pagers required). PC, no.