# Can Framing Frame Day 1 still be completed in stealth if the extra restroom guard spawns?

Tags: payday-2

Occasionally, in Framing Frame Day 1, an additional guard will spawn in the restroom.  This brings the total number of guards on the map to seven:

- One at the front desk.
- One in the security room.
- One in the restroom.
- Four on patrol.

Even with Smooth Talker, you can [only answer four pagers](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/130728) and [dominate one guard](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/128250). That leaves two guards that you need to deal with.

**Is it possible to complete Framing Frame in stealth when this extra guard spawns?**

Answer (score 3):

An alternative approach in case you don't have Joker skill (since it's a very situational skill, and one might not necessarily have room for it in their build) is as follows: (assuming you have the smooth talker skill)

At this point, you have entered the bathroom and killed the bathroom guard in a panic. Take a second to breathe. You now have 4 wandering guards, lobby guard, and cameras, with only 3 pagers and a dominate. We have established that you don't have Joker, so you can only take care of 4 guards.

The plan is as standard: Kill 3 wanderers, dominate 1 (however you want to accomplish this), the only caveat is that you have to ignore the lobby guard, break the cameras, and throw the paintings to the roof (you *do* have the transporter ace, right?), where your other crew members are waiting to catch them (or, if you are doing this solo, you can break the skylights and throw the paintings to the roof. I am told that the lobby guard is deaf). Do note that the lobby guard tends to spot people on the roof **extremely** quickly, so stay far away from that skylight. Hug the walls and you should be fine. Have the crew van the paintings, and sneak out through the bathroom.

As I said, this is a very plan-b approach, and it leaves one guard in play, but it's definitely doable. It just requires a little more care.

Comment: Or you can break the windows on the roof and throw the paintings up when solo, then sneak to the roof to transport them when done.

Comment: @3ventic And the lobby guard is clueless to this?

Comment: Yes, he's totally clueless.